# Magento: Even login users can't write reviews

Tags: magento, review

I have one small problem with Review options in Magento.

Even customer to be login can't write Review, site show next message "Only registered users can write reviews. Please, log in or register". Please see follow image

[Magento http://jovanovjoce.free.fr/images/review.PNG](http://jovanovjoce.free.fr/images/review.PNG)

Necessery is users to have permission to write review, I hope someone have solution for my problem and I will be greatful if shаre with us.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: which magento version you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the control structure to write review :

```
// default/template/review/form.phtml
<?php if ($this->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>

// this function checking the review status, enable or disable

<?php else: ?>
<p class="review-nologged" id="review-form">
    <?php echo $this->__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please, <a href="%s">log in</a> or <a href="%s">register</a>', $this->getLoginLink(), Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl()) ?>
```

So, here is the question :

- Did you disable System -> Configuration -> Advanced Tab / Mage_Review module?

Comment: Hello Oğuz,

I use 1.4.0.1 version on Magento, And in my form.phtml file doesn't have some on code like in you're example, if my code doesn't have  line 
<code>"<?php echo $this->__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please, <a href="%s">log in</a> or <a href="%s">register</a>', $this->getLoginLink(), Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl()) ?>" <code> 
You can see my file next link: https://bitbucket.org/fooman/magento-hg-mirror/src/66bc4a7d4e46/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml

Comment: Mage_Review module is enable, in case to disable this option I will no can see link "Be the first to review this product"

Thanks a lot

Comment: @JovanovJordan impossible, there is no message in 1.4.0.1 edition which I have downloaded right now and checked the message, no result!

Comment: Once again thanks for helping,
Yes, I use the 1.4.0.1 version on magento and for me is strange from where is came this message because in code i can't find this message. I just want to say that i also install extension "Sweet Tooth Point & Review" and perhaps this message come from this extension.